# How can I group data with count of particular item in an Angular filter?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I have a list of players which belong to a group each. How can I use a filter to list the users per group?
I need to get the output with correspong team count also

This is my script.js

```
angular.module('app',['angular.filter'])
  .controller('MainController', function($scope) { 

    $scope.players = [
      {name: 'A', team: 'alpha', score: 10},
      {name: 'B', team: 'beta', score: 14},
      {name: 'C', team: 'gamma', score: 8},
      {name: 'D', team: 'beta', score: 28},
      {name: 'E', team: 'gamma', score: 7},
      {name: 'F', team: 'beta', score: 28},
      {name: 'G', team: 'beta', score: 28},
      {name: 'H', team: 'alpha', score: 10},
      {name: 'I', team: 'beta', score: 28},
      {name: 'J', team: 'gamma', score: 7},
      {name: 'K', team: 'alpha', score: 10},
      {name: 'L', team: 'gamma', score: 7},
      {name: 'M', team: 'gamma', score: 7},
    ];

 });
```

this is my html file

```
  <body>
     <div ng-controller="MainController"> 
       <ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in players | groupBy: 'team'">
     Group name: {{ key }}
     <li ng-repeat="player in value">
       player: {{ player.name }} 
     </li>
     <li>score: {{value | map: 'score' | sum}}</li>
       </ul>
     </div>
  </body>
```

i need to get the output including the corresponding team count as

```
 Group name: alpha 3
 player: A
 player: H
 player: K
 score: 30

Group name: beta 5
 player: B
 player: D
    .
    .
    .
Group name: gamma 5
    .
    .
    .
```

alpha 3 beta 5 gamma 5 are the count of items

Comment: Did I misunderstand your question, but what is wrong with my solution? It does show the team count behind group name.

Comment: Your answer itis correct Jaanus, your solution is perfect i need how it  before binding it to the template thats like foreach if you have just post to me.Sorry your answer is perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the length of group to HTML like this `{{ value.length }}` .

```
<body>
    <div ng-controller="MainController"> 
        <ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in players | groupBy: 'team'">
            Group name: {{ key }}  {{ value.length }} 
            <li ng-repeat="player in value">
                player: {{ player.name }} 
            </li>
            <li>score: {{value | map: 'score' | sum}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could group the array by score before binding it to the template

```
var groupedTeams = {};

var teams = [
  {name: 'A', team: 'alpha', score: 10},
  {name: 'B', team: 'beta', score: 14},
  {name: 'C', team: 'gamma', score: 8},
  {name: 'D', team: 'beta', score: 28},
  {name: 'E', team: 'gamma', score: 7},
  {name: 'F', team: 'beta', score: 28},
  {name: 'G', team: 'beta', score: 28},
  {name: 'H', team: 'alpha', score: 10},
  {name: 'I', team: 'beta', score: 28},
  {name: 'J', team: 'gamma', score: 7},
  {name: 'K', team: 'alpha', score: 10},
  {name: 'L', team: 'gamma', score: 7},
  {name: 'M', team: 'gamma', score: 7},
];

teams.forEach(function(team){
  if (!(team.score in groupedTeams)) {
    groupedTeams[team.score] = [];
  } 
  groupedTeams[team.score].push(team);
});
```

Imo it's better to keep that kinda logic out of your template.

Comment: Its not working KoningDavid .I am new in AngularJS. Please help me to get that.The thing is that my question is the entire thing is iterated and count number of alphas,betas and gammas ie 3 alphas 5 betas and 5 gammas. Please clarify this.I like your code very much thats why i am asking.The logic out of my template.Good Please answer me..